# jquery sortable w/ connectWith: tell which update event is which?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a two lists using jQueryUI's sortable module. I have an update event which is attached to both of them. I have noticed that when I move an element from one list to another, the `update` function is called twice. Is there a way to tell which event is from the list that had an element removed, and which one is the list that received the element?

I am aware of the `receive` and `remove` functions, but I would like to use update to handle cases in which an element is moved within a list and does not change parents. How can I tell which event is which?

Answer (score 0):

From the api docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

You'll probably have to compare the `ui.sender` to the current sortable and decide if it's from a different list then act accordingly. You can also use `this` within the event to get the sortable that just sorted within itself.

```
update:function(even, ui){
   var sortable = ui.sender;

   var htmlElement = this;

}
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the sender is null both for the list that had an element removed, and the list if you just moved two elements within the same list.

Comment: @GSto Updated my answer, `this` will be the sortable that is doing the action. So if `ui.sender` is `null` you'll know it was an item being moved within the same list.